# Rubymotion / Using MotionBundler

Tags: ruby, bundler, rubymotion

Great article to use the ruby's defaults :
[http://blog.rubymotion.com...](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/50983350225/motionbundler-good-old-fashioned-requirements-for)

Everysteps of the setup described works great, but requiring the cgi in a controller [makes the following crash](https://gist.github.com/bbnnt/9667866)

I was previously running with ruby 1.9.3, and everything was working fine. Upgraded on ruby 2.0; it breaks.

Thanks a lot for any feedback on this type of error

Comment: Looks like a ongoing issue https://github.com/archan937/motion-bundler/issues/12

Comment: well many problematic behaviors tend to disappear as you keep using things, this one ended somehow without any clear explanations